# Transfer wordpress site from web server to localhost

Tags: localhost, migration

I recently started a wordpress blog. I manually installed wordpress on the server. But I want some changes to my blog, so I want to do them offline(Localsystem).

I transferred my files to localhost. After transfer I opened in the url "localhost/blog"  main page is showing. When I click the categories section it is redirecting to the main website. When I enter wp-admin it is showing the error "objects not found".

Comment: This question has been answered before. Please search for the existing answer.

Comment: This question has been answered before. Please check it on [this URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989558/moving-wordpress-from-server-to-localhost)

Answer (score 1):

this are the steps you need to care when you setup wordpress locally from server.

1. Download wordpress folder and database.(keep back up)
2. setup db and change on wp_option table for "home_url" and "site_url".
3. change permalink and and reset .htaccess.
4. change on custom menu link which  you have added
5. restart it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way you need to do is install and activate the [Duplicator plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) on your live site. Duplicator plugin allows you to create duplicate package of your entire WordPress site. It can be used to move your WordPress site to a new location, and can also be used as a backup plugin.